# Overwrite issue in merge_vars of Mandrill API

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, mandrill

I am sending email using merge_vars for dynamic contents. Here is how my merge_vars look like:

```
$message['merge_vars'][$index] = array(
  'rcpt' => $email,
  'vars' => array(
    array(
      'name' => 'url',
      'content' => $url
    ),
    array(
      'name' => 'sname',
      'content' => $sname
    ),
    array(
      'name' => 'lname',
      'content' => $lname,
    ),
    array(
      'name' => 'email',
      'content' => $email
    )
  ),
);
```

Everything is working fine. But when same recipient should receive multiple different email in a single API call, then the problem occurs. That time same recipient don't receive different email, he receives same email multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

In a single api call you cannot send different emails to same email address with different merge vars. 
You need to fire multiple api calls having target recipient in each call with respective merge_vars to meet your requirement.

Comment: Yes, I've already got that solution long ago. Thank you anyway.